# Plugin method undefined

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create my first plugin, and when I add an item the `add` function called, so the object logged, but get error about `onAdd is undefined` (see below)

Here is the plugin

```
    $(function () {
    var settings = {
        onAdd: function () {},
        onRemove: function () {},
        sourceSelecter: null,
        targetSelector: null
    };

    $.fn.tokenizer = function (options) {

        settings = $.extend({
            targetSelector: this,
            idName: 'id'
        }, options);

        this.add = function (item) {
            console.log (settings)
            settings.onAdd.call(item);
        };

        this.remove = function (item) {
            settings.onRemove.call(item);
        };
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Here is the console:

> Object { targetSelector: Object, idName: "id", sourceSelector: "group" }
>
> TypeError: settings.onAdd is undefined

Can somebody enlighened me, why is there no `onAdd` function in my `settings`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not including original `settings` object when you extending it. Also I advise you to create `this.settings` field to keep default `settings` separate:

```
$(function() {
  var settings = {
    onAdd: function() {},
    onRemove: function() {},
    sourceSelecter: null,
    targetSelector: null
  };

  $.fn.tokenizer = function(options) {
    this.settings = $.extend({}, {
      targetSelector: this,
      idName: 'id'
    }, settings, options);

    this.add = function(item) {
      console.log(this.settings)
      this.settings.onAdd.call(item);
    };

    this.remove = function(item) {
      this.settings.onRemove.call(item);
    };
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));
```